# ES6: push object into an Array returns array length. How to store it as an array of object in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to push objects into an array and store it in sessionStorage. But array.push of an object returns the length of the array. How do I store the actual object into an array?

[image]
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psw89duc/3/)

```
const counties = {
"Bucks": {
        "countyCode": "42017",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    },
"Montgomery": {
        "countyCode": "42091",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    }
};

let selectedCountiesArray = [];

console.log(selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks'])); // 1
sessionStorage.setItem("tableDisplay", JSON.stringify(selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks'])));
let selectedCounties = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tableDisplay"));
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[{
  countyCode: "42017",
  globalStateCode: "PA",
  stateCode: "PA"
}]
```

Comment: `selectedCountiesArray[selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks']) - 1]`, or store the index in a variable, or rather just push and store using separate statements. You don't need to minify your developement code.

Comment: Why are you passing `seletedCountriesArray.push()` as a parameter? Just push the value into the array in one line and add it to the session storage in the next line?

Comment: @Robo Mop -- can you explain a bit

Comment: @Teemu -- selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks']) - 1. why( - 1)?

Comment: What exactly do you want the tableDisplay to be? The entire `selectedCountiesArray`, or just the latest value added to `selectedCountiesArray`?

Comment: Since I'm assuming you want the entire `selectedCountiesArray` array, why don't you just do `selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks']); sessionStorage.setItem("tableDisplay", JSON.stringify(selectedCountiesArray));` ?

Comment: Because `push` returns the length of the array, which is the last index + 1.

Comment: And like @Teemu said, it seems like you're trying to make the shortest code possible, rather than clean, readable code. Not everything has to be / should be a one liner.

Comment: @RoboMop -- wanted to store specific object. Not the entire object. Object selection is dynamic (ie.) can be either 'Bucks' or 'Montogomery'. This is just a sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to store the return value of array.push() instead of the actual array.

First, push the value to an array and then pass the array as the parameter for **sessionStorage.setItem**

```
const counties = {
"Bucks": {
        "countyCode": "42017",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    },
"Montgomery": {
        "countyCode": "42091",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    }
};

//Push to Array
let selectedCountiesArray = [];
selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks'])

//Set item
sessionStorage.setItem("tableDisplay", JSON.stringify(selectedCountiesArray));


//Get Item
let selectedCounties = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tableDisplay"));
console.log(selectedCounties)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the return value of [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method and it returns

> **Return:** The new length property of the object upon which the method was
> called.

**1)** So, You can set `sessionStorage` data directly an array if you add array element in it as:

```
JSON.stringify([counties['Bucks']])
```

```js
const counties = {
  "Bucks": {
    "countyCode": "42017",
    "globalStateCode": "PA",
    "stateCode": "PA"
  },
  "Montgomery": {
    "countyCode": "42091",
    "globalStateCode": "PA",
    "stateCode": "PA"
  }
};

let selectedCountiesArray = [];

sessionStorage.setItem("tableDisplay", JSON.stringify([counties['Bucks']]));
let selectedCounties = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tableDisplay"));
console.log(selectedCounties);
```

**2)** You can push elements to array and then use `setItem` to set Item in `sessionStorage`

```js
const counties = {
  "Bucks": {
    "countyCode": "42017",
    "globalStateCode": "PA",
    "stateCode": "PA"
  },
  "Montgomery": {
    "countyCode": "42091",
    "globalStateCode": "PA",
    "stateCode": "PA"
  }
};

let selectedCountiesArray = [];

selectedCountiesArray.push(counties['Bucks']);
sessionStorage.setItem("tableDisplay", JSON.stringify(selectedCountiesArray));
let selectedCounties = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tableDisplay"));
console.log(selectedCounties);
```